# How can I cache dataset at intermediate step of query in spark sql when I have query in string form and not in dataframe API form?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting some inputs from upstream which are **sql queries in string form, input file paths and table view name**.
For execution time improvements on cluster, I want to cache my dataset for one query and reuse the same dataset for other queries.

**For ex** - consider the following dataset **IPL**.

```
# player_name #  |  # team #  |  # country #  |  # runs #

sachin           |   csk      |    IND        |   12000
sehwag           |   DC       |    IND        |   18000
MOEN             |   RCB      |    UK         |   10000
WATSON           |   CSK      |    AUS        |   11000
```

and so on.....

**I have following queries.**

1. Select team, sum(runs) as total_run from IPL where runs > 12000 group by team.
2. Select country, sum(runs) as total_run from IPL where runs > 12000 group by country.

both of these queries are using the same filtered dataset which is **runs > 12000** and there can be n such queries which can use the same result as above. **how can I cache the dataset after filtering here?** so that same computation does not take place more than once.

**Note:** we can easily do this if we are using the dataframe APIs by splitting up the query.

ex -

```
Dataset<Row> result1 = df.where("runs > 12000").select("team", "run")
                        .groupby("team").agg(count("run").as(""total_run));

Dataset<Row> result2 = df.where("runs > 12000").select("country", "run") 
                        .groupby("country").agg(count("run").as(""total_run));
```

we can break it as....

```
    Dataset<Row> cachedResult = df.where("runs > 12000").select("team", "run");
    
    Dataset<Row> result1 = cachedResult.groupby("team").agg(count("run").as(""total_run));
    
    Dataset<Row> result2 = df.where("runs > 12000").select("country", "run")
                            .groupby("country").agg(count("run").as(""total_run));
```

**simply, my questions are,**

1. how we can achieve caching and other similar
   operation when we have spark sql query in string form?
2. do I need to split up the sql query into mutliple string? I can do
   it here but it will be very much cumbersome for a big sql query?
3. can I convert sql string to dataframe APIs using some library
   because it will be very difficult to convert it manually